# Can't get modal to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, materialize

I've literally copied and pasted the modal html, css, and javascript fro w3schools into my html and I still can't get this simple modal to show up.

Here is the relevant html.

```
 <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

     <!-- The Modal -->
     <div id="myModal" class="modal">
         <!-- Modal content -->
         <div class="modal-content">
             <span class="close">&times;</span>
             <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Here is the css.

```
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1000; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And the javascript...

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
};

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

This is all copied from w3schools how to section [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp).

I am using Materialize on the site as well. And they DO have some css classes with the same name, modal, but I'm loading the above styles after I load the material css, and loading the javascript after I load the material javascript.

What happens is when the button is clicked, it will change colors, but the span and the p tag with the text never show. When I click off of the button, the color goes back to the default. So it's like it's working but it's not showing the modal.

I've been working on this for way too long, hence why I've finally just copied and pasted the w3schools code. But. it's still not working. Can someone please fix this before I bang my head on my desk?

Comment: Its working on the fiddle that I created using both materialize js and css and the code you gave. May be something else on your page is not letting the modal to trigger. Can you share the url where it isnt working ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to share the url because teh site isn't deployed or anything. What do you mean?

Comment: First thought is this is happening because your script is coming before the HTML in your file so it's trying to manipulate elements that haven't been created yet.  But, since you're not posting your actual code it's a bit early to tell.

Comment: The script tags are loaded right before the closing body tag

Comment: You're still not showing us your actual code.  You claim it's like the code you pasted, but ... it's probably not.  Scrap all code in your question and post your actual code please.

Comment: it is lol. I've literally copied and pasted the code from w3schools. Would you like the rest of the html, css, and javascript? i'll happily email you the files, but i can't past it all in a comment

Comment: Edit your question.  There's an edit button just below the tags.

Comment: Ok, so the issue was that I have some script for another page on the site that was in the same script file, but before the code for the modal. I moved the code for the modal above it. Is there a different way to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix your custom class with something, so that they don't conflict with `materializecss`. Here I used `_` as a prefix to remove the conflict.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('_myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('_close')[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
};

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

```css
._modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1000; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
._modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
._close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

._close:hover,
._close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="section">
   <button id="myBtn" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light orange">Open Modal</button>

     <!-- The Modal -->
     <div id="_myModal" class="_modal">
         <!-- Modal content -->
         <div class="_modal-content">
             <span class="_close">&times;</span>
             <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that helped i'm sure. but the problem was that I have some other script that is for another page, and i was getting an error because the element called in that script was undefined on the page I'm trying to call the modal in. Do you know of a way that I can fix that issue?

Comment: When you're using such kind of library, eigher you've to fully rely on the library or use to different name from libray if you want custom style. There is nothing to do.

Comment: You can use `materializecss`'s own modal.

Comment: I know but it's for a class so I've got to show that I can write some custom script. I've got it working. Thanks for your help.